# Splitting a query string?

Tags: c#, .net, query-string

this may seem like a stupid question but I have a query string which passes a unique id across pages, What I am wondering is how I would split the following so that I have just the id?

```
property-buildings_e1.aspx?SubPage=561
```

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Request.QueryString("SubPage")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int subPage = 0;
if(Request.QueryString["SubPage"] != null)
    subPage = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["SubPage"]);
```

Comment: This just calls Int32.Parse, you should consider using TryParse instead which is a 'nicer' way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the value of SubPage

```
Request.Params["SubPage"]
```

or

```
Request.QueryString["SubPage"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

[HttpUtility.ParseQueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.web.httputility.parsequerystring.aspx).

```
NameValueCollection parts = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(query);
string subPage = parts["SubPage"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access it using

```
Request.Querystring("SubPage")
```